# How to get 'Alt' field value of Sitecore media item by Sitecore Scriban embedded method?

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am able to get the Sitecore media link by using the Sitecore Scriban Embedded method as follows:

```
<img src="{{sc_follow i_article 'Thumbnail'| sc_medialink}}">
```

But, not sure how to get the value of the `Alt` field value of the Sitecore Media item using the Sitecore Scriban Embedded functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{{i_datasource.Image}}` or `{{ i_item.Image}}` to get image src and alt. Here `.Image` is the image type field name, in your case, it seems like *Thumbnail*. so, it should be `{{i_datasource.Thumbnail}}`

Scriban code should be something like this:

```
<div class="some-class">
{{i_datasource.Image}}
</div>
```

The output will be:

```
<div class="some-class">
<img src="/-/media/Project/Sites/image-name.png" alt="image-alt">
</div>
```

Refer to this documentation for more details: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/scriban-templates.html

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks @Raman

Comment: Just posting the further in addition to this helpful answer that if you want only src and alt attributes then use it like src "{{i_article.Thumbnail.media_url}}" alt="{{i_article.Thumbnail.alt}}", otherwise it will add height and width attribute that can not be suitable in the mobile view.

Comment: As @PrashantTomar indicated, this is not the true answer as it adds height and width. Thank you Prashant for posting the actual answer in your comment but I wish you had posted it and marked it as the correct answer.